# How to customize the validations in rails if the request comes from specific controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

lets say that I want to make the possibility of posting two types of posts [long] and [short] sharing the same table [id, title, content, short:boolean, user_id] and model

and the user chose to post short post and the site only will store the content and it will be under 120 char, to recognize it we will put the short:true, but how to customize the validations if it chose short to allow empty title and content under 120 char ..... etc

Comment: It depends on what Rails version you use. In latest version there is possibility to set custom validation context.

Comment: But in more complex application it's better to use form objects imho.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to solve your problem is conditional validations. Your model should be like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, unless: :short?
  validates :title, absence: true, if: :short?
  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :content, length: { maximum: 120 }, if: :short?
end
```

I'm not sure i understood all conditions in your example right, hope this code is enough to make what you want.

Also you may read details about conditional validations in [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `short` boolean field on Post, you can simply add these helper methods

```
class Post < AR 
  # this method is automatically generated by rails
  def short?
    short
  end

  def long?
    !short
  end
end
```

And then add `if:` or `unless:` to your validations:

```
validates :content, length: { maximum: 120 }, if: :short?
validates :content, presence: true, if: :long?
```

Comment: but the controller side should i create new countroller for short posts

Comment: no, just create the object with all the params, the validations will do the rest